# After converting a pdf to swf, how can I select text to highlight?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, pdf, flash

I have used a tool to convert a pdf to a swf but i need to be able to select and hightlight the pdf's contents. How would I do this using flex/action script?
Thank you!

Comment: Select the texts? What tool are you using?

Comment: i'm using adobe's flex builder, I want to use the cursor to select text for highlighting

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just use ordinar HTML page to display that pdf's content + iframe to display the page. It's really easy. Check this: [Flex + HTML](http://flex-blogger.com/blog/2010/12/11/flex-and-html-embedded-in-iframe/). Enjoy!